# OleDbException No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, excel

I have a windows service that updates each row of an excel file of type .xlsm with business logic results.

> Connection string : Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\excel.xlsm;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;"

update statement : `UPDATE[Sheet1$AT3:AY3] SET F1 = 0.00, F2 = 0.00, F3 = '2100',F4 = '2',F5 = 'Valid',F6 = 0`

I'm using Microsoft Database Engine 2007.

I have searched through out the internet and have implemented all the recommendations none seem to work. I have also went to the route of using Interop dll but the problem with it it needs Office installed on the server.

Can any one point me to a right direction?

Comment: This error message usually means that one or more of your column name or table name are not recognized as valid names, however I have tried your simple code and no error pops up

Comment: I found the answer my excel spread sheet had filters and was not providing a filter value

Comment: You could provide your own answer detailing the problem and the process to solve it. I think that this could be very interesting to future readers.